# what is esx max volume size?

Tags: vmware-esx, lun

had trouble making esxi4 see datastore of size 2TB. It is said this is max for a LUN only and could be bypassed by extents?
how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's LVM-based so 2TB per extent, you can have up to 32 extents per datastore however, just open the datastore and add a second extent. Beware however that although v4 is better at dealing with extent-loss not killing the whole datastore it is still possible, it's not actually good practice to have particularly large datastores either, although it comes in handy every now and then.

Comment: the prob i am running into is dell perc6i is exposing 6*600gb as 2.87 in R5 which esx4 cant install. is there a way by changing block size?

Comment: Ah, your actual presented LUNs have to be in 2TB chunks.